# matching django url with views using a model slug

Tags: django, django-urls

my problem is that I can not establish a reverse match, most likely doing something wrong with my url definition (?). Ultimately what I am trying to do is the following:

User selects 2 location points which the 'new_pointview' view, saves into a DB. I also define a unique slug which contains location information and save it to the DB via the save() within the model. Then the user should be redirected to a url (pointview view) which uses the slug I created in the previous step i.e /pointview/slug. Here is the code:

models.py

```
class Points(models.Model):
    starting_point_longitude = models.FloatField(null=True)
    starting_point_latitude = models.FloatField(null=True)
    ending_point_longitude = models.FloatField(null=True)
    ending_point_latitude = models.FloatField(null=True)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True, unique=True, blank=False)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url = 'start_lon-{0}-start_lat-{1}-end_lon-{2}-end_lat-' \
                   '{3}'.format(self.starting_point_longitude,
                                self.starting_point_latitude,
                                self.ending_point_longitude,
                                self.ending_point_latitude)

        super(Points, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('pointview', kwargs={'url': self.url})
```

views.py

```
def pointview(request, url):
    point = get_object_or_404(Points, url=url)
    content = {'starting_point_longitude':
               point.starting_point_longitude,
               'starting_point_latitude':
               point.starting_point_latitude,
               'ending_point_longitude':
               point.ending_point_longitude,
               'ending_point_latitude':
               point.ending_point_latitude}
    
    return render(request, 'points.html', {'user_bundle': content})

def new_pointview(request):
    Points.objects.create(
        starting_point_longitude=request.POST['starting_point_longitude'],
        starting_point_latitude=request.POST['starting_point_latitude'],
        ending_point_longitude=request.POST['ending_point_longitude'],
        ending_point_latitude=request.POST['ending_point_latitude'],
    )

    points_filtered = Points.objects.filter(
        starting_point_longitude=request.POST[
            'starting_point_longitude']).filter(
                starting_point_latitude=request.POST[
                    'starting_point_latitude'])
    unique_url = points_filtered.values()[0]['url']

    return redirect('/pointview/{0}/'.format(unique_url))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^pointview/(?P<url>[-\w]+)/$', views.pointview, name='pointview'),
    path('^new_pointview/', views.new_pointview, name='new_pointview'),
]
```

The error:
The current path, pointview/start_lon-738949.9146592747-start_lat--153698.8751025315-end_lon-759997.8063993475-end_lat--168467.65638300427/, didn't match any of URL patterns. Hope you can give me some feedback here..

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, it was a regex problem, using the following non intuitive regex solved it:

```
url('^pointview/(?P<url>start_lon[--W]+start_lat[--W]+end_lon[--W]+end_lat[--W]+)/', views.pointview, name='pointview')
```

I would be very interesting though if someone can give a more elegant solution.